# what is the size of a block in Hyperledger v0.6?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, consensus

According to the answer to ([How are Hyperledger transactions ordered in a block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985388/how-are-hyperledger-transactions-ordered-in-a-block?rq=1)), in Hyperledger v0.6 there is a leader that is ordering transactions in a block.

How the number of transactions in a block is set up? or it is frequency of creation a new block? How to define/modify it?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for posting this as a separate question and not a new answer! (We actually have a problem with that.)

Answer (score 2):

For Fabric v0.6 there is a file `fabric/consensus/pbft/config.yaml`. This is a configuration for PBFT consensus with default values:

```
general:
    batchsize: 500
    timeout:
        batch: 1s
```

It means that new block will be generated when one of these conditions(any of them) is met:

- There are 500 transactions in a buffer
- 1 second passed from time when previous block was generated.

For NOOPS consensus new block is generated for every transaction.

Comment: Thank you! 
And is it correct that for pbft implementation, leader' chose is random among VP?
(could not find these details in Fabric documentation or in the code)

Comment: There was a requirement for v0.6 that peers should be named vp0, vp1, vp2, ... vpn. As far as I saw in slack channel, the leader is selected in the same order (vp0 by default).